# CSS to show the center of my image on responsive mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a website with a logo image on a div inside a showcase section...
I want my image to be responsive on mobile... to show the center of my image, currently my website is only showing the left corner.

This is my html code:

```
<section id="showcase">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Espaço para eventos Roda D'Água</h1>
  <p>Um ótimo lugar para confraternizações, reuniões familiares e outros eventos.</p>
</div>
```

This is my showcase css:

```
#showcase {
  min-height:400px;
  background:url('SrcImgHere') no-repeat 0 -400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

What should I change to show the center of my image on mobile?
Link to my website if you want to "live" test: 
http://espacorodadagua.dx.am/index.php

Comment: add `background-position:center`

Comment: Thank you, Peter G, my english is not the best...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `background-position: center;` to center the background image.

If you would like the position to change only for mobile -

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    #showcase {
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need for this is `background-position` css attribute.

**Syntax**

```
/* Keyword values */
background-position: top;
background-position: bottom;
background-position: left;
background-position: right;
background-position: center;

/* <percentage> values */
background-position: 25% 75%;

/* <length> values */
background-position: 0 0;
background-position: 1cm 2cm;
background-position: 10ch 8em;

/* Multiple images */
background-position: 0 0, center;

/* Edge offsets values */
background-position: bottom 10px right 20px;
background-position: right 3em bottom 10px;
background-position: bottom 10px right;
background-position: top right 10px;

/* Global values */
background-position: inherit;
background-position: initial;
background-position: unset;
```

You could use css media queries to target different Media features such as viewport sizes, device sizes, device orientations etc

In your case to center the background image you could use value 'center'

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 #showcase  {
   background-position: center;
 }
}
```

**Useful links**

- Media Queries: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
- Background-position: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Comment: Thank you for you help 
`background-position:center` 
solved my problem
I'll read about Media Queries to use it on my website, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code working:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
#showcase {
  background-position: center;
}}
```

Thank y'all for helping me!!!!